# How to build Dialer/Phone application from the source code?

Tags: android

Hi i am trying to write test cases for "phone" native application , so i am trying to build that application from the source code...
It has some dependency with the Contacts app , i am not able to resolve that . Any help regarding writing test cases for phone app or help on building it is very much helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot build the "phone" native application outside of building the entire firmware.